# Windows Server 2008, rejoining domain fails

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I have two windows 2008 servers, which have been unjoined from the domain for a long time.

I tried to rejoin them to previous domain and one of the servers could rejoin successfully, but the other one failed with the error: `The following error occurred attempting to join the domain "my.domain"; Logon Failure: The target account name is incorrect.`

I'm sure I used the right account, but still can't join to domain.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Is the server still in AD? Try removing it from AD before you add it.

Comment: Really thanks all of your reminder! After I remove the host name from doamin, I could re-join this computer. Thanks a lot! Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

Check if, by any chance, there isn't already a computer account with the same name in the destination domain.

Comment: Yes, I found this computer host name is already in destination domain.

Comment: Really thanks all of your reminder!
After I remove the host name from doamin, I could re-join this computer.
Thanks a lot!

Best Regards

Comment: Np. Just remember to accept the answer if it was the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following on the machine on which you are unable to add to the domain:

```
arp -d *
nbtstat -R
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and then reboot the machine